# system crashed after changing /etc permission

Tags: 14.04

os- ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Unfortunately i changed permission of my /etc folder
I ran following command

```
      sudo chmod -R 777 /etc
```

and after this my system crashed.

When I tried to reboot it, it keeps showing a warning -

```
                 system booting without full network configuration
```

and not booting at all.

How can I fix this?Because all my data and project are in there and I don't want to reinstall OS.
Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try ubuntu live and, first of all, copy your data somewhere else.
Then you can reinstall system - or you can try to restore original permissions on files in /etc, if that's really all that happened. But anyway - it may be messy after all. But you know the best what exactly you did. Pick your approach, whatever works better for you and seems quicker. You may want to compare permissions with another, original system.

Comment: can i use    pkexec chmod -R  0440 /etc/
sudoers   to fix this.